# An urn contains two red balls and four white balls. Sample successively five times at random and with replacement so that the trials are independent.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, independence

An urn contains two red balls and four white balls. Sample successively five times at random and with replacement so that the trials are independent. 
Compute the probability of each of the two sequences

WWRWR

RWWWR

Please explain. I have the correct answer but i do not understand how to get it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

If $A$ and $B$ two independant events, $P(A \cap B) = P(A)*P(B)$

Answer (score 0):

The probability to draw a white ball is $\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}$.

The probability to draw a red ball is $\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$.

After drawing there is replacement so that these probabilities stand each of the $5$ times.

Then the chance to draw e.g. **RWRRR** equals $$\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{3}$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$P(WWRWR) = P(W)P(W)P(R)P(W)P(R) = \frac{4}{6} \frac{4}{6} \frac{2}{6} \frac{4}{6} \frac{2}{6}$

$P(WWRWR) = P(W)P(W)P(R)P(W)P(R)$ follows by independence.

where W = event a white ball is drawn, R = event a red ball is drawn

WWRWR = event a white ball is drawn the fisrt time, a white ball is drawn the second time, a red ball is drawn the third time, a white ball is drawn the fourth time and a red ball is drawn the fifth time

Comment: A downvote just because I gave away the answer? Seriously?

Comment: Solving a question completely when OP shows no effort is not good practice on this site.

Comment: @5xum I agree, but is it enough as reason to downvote? Btw, only one of the answers was given and it is accompanied by an explanation. I will compensate. Downvoting=saying that this answer is not useful.

Comment: @5xum, drhab did so too...

Comment: @BCLC And he also hot a downvote.

Comment: @5xum You sure? >:)

Comment: @5xum and drhab was compensated too :)

Comment: @BCLC Yes. Click on the number $0$ next to his answer, you will se he has one downvote and one upvote.

Comment: @5xum Ah I see.